# Inconsistent result for String.getBytes()

Tags: java, string, encoding, arrays

```
System.out.println("hello world".getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

occasionally returns a different value, why is that??

Sorry, I'm still a noob at Java.

Comment: Please show us: (1) the complete compilable code; (2) what you normally get from it; (3) what you occasionally get.

Comment: on the same machine, using the same JVM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code prints an array (byte[]), but there is no standard array printing in Java. So instead of printing the content of the array, the code displays some cryptic memory reference to the array. Eg "[B@6bbc4459". This information is not very useful and is likely to change between programm executions.

If you want to display the content of the array, you must iterate through it.

Answer (score 4):

You're printing the result of calling `toString()` on a byte array. That *doesn't* show you the contents, as arrays don't override `toString()` - it's just showing you something like `[B@ABCDEF01` where the `[B` shows that it's a byte array, and the value after the @ is a hash code.

If you want to show the byte array contents as numbers, you want something like [`Arrays.toString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28byte%5B%5D%29):

```
byte[] data = "hello world".getBytes("UTF-8");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
```